# Classification of surfaces with projectively isomorphic hyperplane sections in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

A projective variety $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ has projectively isomorphic plane sections if there is an open set $U\in(\mathbb{P}^n)^\vee$ such that the hyperplane sections $H\cap X,\ H\in U$ are all projectively isomorphic. In the paper "Some Remarks on Varieties with Projectively
Isomorphic Hyperplane Sections" Rita Pardini writes:

> Actually, in 1925 Fubini and Fano classified surfaces with
> projectively isomorphic hyperplane sections in $\mathbb{P}^3$ by
> different methods (see [Fubini, G.: Sulle varies a sezioni piane collineari, Rend. Accad. Naz. Lincei I (1925),
> 469-473.
> ] and [Fano, G.: Sulle superficie dello spazio $S_3$ a sezioni piane collineari, Rend. Accad. Naz. Lincei
> I (1925), 473--477.]) ...
> The related problem of classifying smooth projective hypersurfaces with isomorphic hyperplane sections has been recently solved by Beauville ([Beauville, A.: Sur les hypersurfaces dont les section hyperplanes sont ~t module constant,
> GrothendieckFestschrift, Vol. I, Birkh~iuser, 1990, pp. 121-133. ])

Unfortunately, all three of these references are in either Italian or French. Are there any English references for these results, or English translations of these papers? Or maybe somebody here already knows these results?

Comment: Try "Varieties with isomorphic or birational hyperplane sections", by James McKernan.